# Duda con el ciclo For

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

¿cómo podría hacer para que este programa imprima en reverso los números impares separados con coma hacia el 0?

```
numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

start , end = 1, numero
for x in range(start, end +1 ):

    if x % 2 != 0:
        print(x, end=" " )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EJ: 9 : 7 5 3 1 0**

Answer (score 1):

En principio solo deberías invertir el funcionamiento de [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) para que cuente de forma regresiva, esto lo logras invirtiendo `start` y `stop` y definiendo el paso o `step` en -1:

```
start , end = numero, 1
for x in range(start, end - 1 , -1):

    if x % 2 != 0:
        print(x, end=" " )
```

Incluso podrías hacer algo más óptimo, ya que `range()` permite establecer un `step`, puedes evitarte el `if` si estableces un paso de -2:

```
start , end = numero, 1
for x in range(start, end - 1 , -2):
  print(x, end=" " )
```

Comment: El  codigo sin el if solo funcionará si el número que entra por input es impar, por ejemplo si numero = 24 imprimira: "24 22 20 18 16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2"

Comment: Es una buena aclaración @AnkiJedi, para el caso concreto de este ejemplo, se debería validar que el número de entrada sea impar